# php Set tmp directory

Tags: php, apache, osticket

I have an Apache server running on RHEL 6.5. For the past few days I have been trying to install OSticket, an open source ticket system, and keep getting this error when trying to access the setup directory with my browser.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/u00/apache_homes/sdm/:.:/u00/app/php/lib/php/) in
>   /u00/apache_homes/sdm/htdocs/support/setup/setup.inc.php on line 53
>
> Fatal error: session_start() [function.session-start]: Failed to
>   initialize storage module: files (path: ) in
>   /u00/apache_homes/sdm/htdocs/support/setup/setup.inc.php on line 53

Now I know the issue is that the page dose not have permission to access the /tmp directory. I cannot give it access for security reasons according to the server admin. We do have another tmp directory set up under the Apache folder.

My question is this. Is it possible to specify a override to use this new directory globally as the tmp directory? Is it upload_tmp_dir in the php.ini what I am looking for?

Comment: Have you tried looking at their documentation? also, have you looked into the `setup.inc.php` to see how it it setting the folder to the temp directory?

Comment: Hi Hoss, I tried looking at the documentation and could not find anything. I have also searched through the site files looking for anything that sets a tmp directory without any luck. Whats odd is I cannot find the function that is called on line 53, just the call.